# What is the difference between having a class as final and having a class constructor as private

Tags: java, constructor, final

What exactly is the difference between a final class and having a class constructor as private.

I know both can't be subclassed(correct me if i am wrong). Is their any difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A final class cannot be extended. It prevents this

```
final class FinalClass {

}

// and later

class ExtendedClass extends FinalClass { // ERROR

}
```

This is useful for things like String - you wouldn't want someone to be able to overwrite the logic of String, one of the most commonly used Objects, and be able to, oh I don't know, add networking and send all the strings back you use. It's possible to do if you can extend String.

A private constructor cannot be called outside the class.

```
class PrivateCons {

    private PrivateCons() {

    }
}

// later
PrivateCons pc = new PrivateCons(); // ERROR
```

Often this ends up working like this: (java.lang.Math is a good example)

```
class FuncLib {
    private FuncLib() { } // prevent instantiation
    public static void someFunc(...) { }
    public static int anotherFunc(...) { }
}
```

Or it ends up working like this // Integer does this actually

```
class VerySpecial {

    private static Map<String,VerySpecial> cache;

    public static VerySpecial generate(String data) {
        VerySpecial result = cache.get(data);
        if(result == null) {
            result = new VerySpecial(data);
            cache.put(data,result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String data;

    private VerySpecial() { }

    private VerySpecial(String data) { this.data = data}

}
```

When you extend a class, your constructor by default attempts to call the default (no argument) constructor. If that is private, then you must explicitly call a non-private constructor when you extend it. If you have no non-private constructors to call you won't be able to extend it. *Thanks for comments for pointing this out. :-)*

Comment: can you extend a class that has all its constructors as private?

Comment: If all of your constructors are private, you wouldn't be able to extend the class

Comment: Would the JVM be able to optimize for a final class better than one with all private constructors? (Not that we should care about optimization unless there's a real, measurable problem, but out of interest...).

Comment: @glowCoder u mean to say for final classes we can have the instance of the class created but for the class with private constructor we can't create an instance.

Comment: @Russell well, yes it would optimize better, but you also lose a lot of leverage. I suppose you can always make it un-final if you need to extend it as that won't break any API (like it would if you made it final after release).

Comment: @Adam Strictly speaking you could create inner classes that extends the outer class, but yeah, beyond that you can't extend the class.

Comment: So I'm up to 3 downvotes on this. I felt I addressed any issues that were brought up, both in the mechanics and how they are commonly used. Is there anything else that can be done to improve it? I'd be happy to address further issues left in comments. :-)

Answer (score 5):

## Instantiation

- You can't instantiate a class with a private constructor. But you can use it as an utility class with static methods.
- A final class can be instantiated but not extended, obviously you cant extend a class with
  a private constructor either as the implicit super() call would fail.

Look at the Math class it has a private constructor, can't be instantiated yet it has many static methods which are very helpful

Comment: You can instantiate a class with a private constructor.  It is necessary for example with the pattern MyObject.newInstance(), where newInstance calls the private constructor.  (This is necessary when you cannot use a normal constructor because it would leak the `this` reference.)

Comment: newInstance() will an throw an IllegalAccessException unless you have used a Constructor with setAccessible(true).

Comment: @Peter Sorry.  I just meant a home-made newInstance, nothing with reflection.  It's just a static method that returns a new instance build from the private constructor.

Comment: @toto2, You can use `Constructor.newInstance()` (after changing the access), just not `MyClass.class.newInstance()`

Answer (score 1):

Having only private constructors is stronger than having a final class.

In detail:
Having only private constructors in a class A strongly influences object creation. Usually you are then using a factory method. You can still create instances of A without a factory method using tricks, such as clone() or invoking the private constructor reflectively. But **subclassing is not possible**, because a subclass' constructor needs to be able to call `super()`. That would only be possible within a nested class inside A.

Having only private constructors often makes sense, e.g. to control instantiations via factory methods, e.g. for singeltons (see Effective Java item 3). But even in that case, I don't see a reason to not writing "final class", if just for documentation, so that readers immediately grasp that subclassing is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your class to be sub-classed, then you use final. If you don't want other classes to instantiate your class, but rather you want to control how the object is constructed and maintained, you use private constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A final class/method can never be inherited/overridden and will throw compilation error where as A class with private constructor will also throw compilation that'There is no default constructor is available for your class' and once u add a non final constructor and call it from your child class, There will be no error.

A private constructor is useful in case of creating singleton class(Only one instance of a class can exist),Where you make your constructor private and a variable to store single instance,which will be exposed with public static method.
for ex.

```
public class Singleton{    
private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

//private constructor to avoid client applications to use constructor
private Singleton(){}

public static Singleton getInstance(){
    return instance;
}}
```

And for example String class in java is a final class.

Answer (score 0):

`private` members can be accessed by inner classes.

```
public class Outer {
  private Outer() {
    System.out.println("Outer()");
  }

  static class Inner extends Outer {
    {
      System.out.println("Inner()");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    new Inner();
  }
}
```

prints

```
Outer()
Inner()
```

A final class cannot be extended, but its constructor can be public.  A private constructor can be called from another constructor or used by an inner class.