# Why does a private base class constructor result in "Implicit super constructor is not visible"

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, private

If constructors do not inherits in Java, why do I get compile error(Implicit super constructor A() is not visible for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor)?

```
class A {
    private A() {
    }
}

public class B extends A {

}
```

UPD. I know that `super()` is called in implicit B constructor. But i don't get why it can't access private constructor with `super()`. So, if we have only private constructors, class de facto is `final`?

Comment: (The answer to your final question is "yes", provided you mean by "final" that "it can't be subclassed".  It should (probably, I think) not be assumed however that the compiler will also spot this and treat class A exactly the same as if it had explicitly been declared "final".)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve 'Implicit super constructor classA() is not visible. Must explicitly invoke another constructor'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904355/how-to-resolve-implicit-super-constructor-classa-is-not-visible-must-explici)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if `B extends A`, `B` must have an access to an `A` constructor.

Keep in mind that a constructor always call `super()`.
So here, the implicit parameterless constructor of `B` can't call the `A` constructor.

Comment: I know that super() is called in implicit B constructor. But i don't get why it can't access private constructor with super(). So, if we have only private constructors class de facto is final?

Comment: @OlegKuts You're confusing some stuff here ! A constructor cannot be `final`, in fact, the JLS specified a constructor can't be overrided. So, the `B` constructor isn't overriding the `A` constructor, but just calling it. Setting your `A` constructor `private` means it can't be used outside the `A` class, and so can't be used in the `B` class, but the `B` constructor need the `A` constructor, and that's why you got the error `super constructor A() is not visible for default constructor` :) Hope it help !

Comment: maybe I should use commas...) I mean that class became final, when all constructors are set to private.

Comment: @OlegKuts Oh sorry, my english is broken :P It's a good question actually, already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337079/what-is-the-difference-between-having-a-class-as-final-and-having-a-class-constr) ;)

Answer (score 3):

In Java, if you create an instance of `Child Class`, `Parent Class` instance gets created implicitly. 
So Child Class constructor should be visible to `Child Class` as it calls the constructor of `Parent Class` constructor using `super()` in the first statement itself.

So if you change the constructor of the `Parent Class` to `private`, `Child Class` could not access it and could not create any instance of its own, so compiler on the first hand just does not allow this at all.

But if you want to `private` default constructor in `Parent Class`, then you need to explicitly create an overloaded `public` constructor in the `Parent Class` & then in `Child class` constructor you need to call using `super(param)` the public overloaded constructor of `Parent Class` .

Moreover, you might think then what's the use of `private` constructors. `private` constructors is mostly used when you don't want others from any external class to call `new()` on your class. So in that case, we provide some `getter()` method to provide out class's `object`.In that method you can create/use existing Object of your class & return it from that method.

Eg. `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`. This actually forms the basis of `Singleton` design pattern.

Comment: thanks, I know that. My question is why super() cannot call private constructor? Is it the same reason for private methods cannot be overridden?

Comment: super() cannot call `Parent` class `private` constructors simply because `private` members are only accessible within the same class, so `Child` class being a different class you just simply can't access it.

Comment: @OlegKuts If this worked for you, you can set this as a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

The important point is to understand that the first line of any constructor is to call the super constructor. The compiler makes your code shorter by inserting super() under the covers, if you do not invoke a super constructor yourself.

Now if you make that constructor in superclass private, above mentioned concept will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your class B has a default constructor, B() - because you didn't explicitly define any other one.
That constructor implicitly calls its super constructor, A().
But you have explicitly made that one private to class A, so you have explicitly declared that no other class, including B, can have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Can work

```
class A {
    private A() {
    }
    public A(int i){
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    private A(){
        super(10);
    }
}
```

Or remove the private A(), defaults to public A(), 
unless you have another constructor

```
class A {

}

public class B extends A {
    private A(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An instance of class `B` creates an instance of class `A` so `B` must invoke `super(...)` if `A` implements a non default constractor. So the constructor should be `protected` for `B` being able to call `super(...)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class B extends A {

/*
* The default constructor B means
* public () B {super();}
*/
   public B() {
   }
}
```

So you should define a constructor which is accessible by the class `B`

1. You can change the access modifier for parent Constructor
2. Or else you can define other Constructor in parent class which is accessible by class `B` and call that constructor.